# Thread reusability using a Queue (two way communication between threads)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have one controller thread which is queuing the task in batch size of 20 tasks and there are n number of tasks. Now I have 20 threads for executing each task and if each thread completed the task , I want to reuse it again to get task from the queue. I m newbie to threads synchronization so pardon me. I am unable to reuse the threads. It is executing 1 batch that is 20 threads executed and finished.

```
Queue<Action> queueComputersToScan = new Queue<Action>();
ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
int batchsize = 20;
Thread controllerThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Math.Ceiling((decimal)GetListOfComputers().Count / batchsize); x++)
    {
        List<ComputerInformation> computers = new List<ComputerInformation>
            (GetListOfComputers().Skip(x * batchsize).Take(batchsize));

        foreach (var computer in computers)
        {
            queueComputersToScan.Enqueue(() => ScanComputer(computer));
        }

        // when queue will have 20 jobs this event signal child threads to work on it 
        manualResetEvent.Set();
    }
});
controllerThread.Start();`
```

Code for 20 worker thread:

```
int maxThread = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < maxThread; i++)
{
    List<FileInformation> fileInformationPerComputer = new List<FileInformation>();
    string threadName = string.Empty;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            if (manualResetEvent.WaitOne())
            {
                if (queueComputersToScan.Count > 0)
                {
                    Action scanComputerJob = queueComputersToScan.Dequeue();
                    if (scanComputerJob != null)
                    {
                        scanComputerJob();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.Name = "Thread on" + threadName;
    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(thread.Name.ToLower() + " has started");
    threadsPerComputer.Add(thread);
}
```

The output of above program is it is getting 20 jobs from queue and after that it stopped fetching other jobs from queue. It is one way communication, worker threads are not again fetching from queue (that I want to fix).

I am bit confused on two way communication or inter communication between controller thread and worker threads. I want to achieve this
Controller thread fetch 20 jobs then controller stops and signal 20 threads to work on 20 jobs.
When Workers thread finished the 20 jobs then workers stop and signal controller thread to fetch next 20 jobs and controller thread stop and again signal the workers to work again on 20 jobs until queue gets empty.

Comment: TL;DR but since the code is not using ConcurrentQueue it is unlikely correct.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [TPL dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) as alternative

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ya

Comment: In 2021, you shouldn't generally be thinking "I'll create threads, and locks, and manage synchronization, etc". You should be thinking "what are some high level abstractions that allow me to work with my problem rather than the mechanics of threading". For starters, it appears all of your threads will only run sequentially since they all compete for a lock and do all of their work within it. That's not right.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever all were starter at start :)

Comment: Have you looked at the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class? It's essentially a thread-safe queue, with embedded inter-thread communication features.

Comment: @MiralShah - yes, but if someone offers me a car ride, I don't expect them to then sit down and try constructing an internal combustion engine. Most people these days don't know (nor need to know) all of the mechanisms involved.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
int batchsize = 20;

IObservable<Unit> query =
    GetListOfComputers()
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(computer => Observable.Start(() => ScanComputer(computer)))
        .Merge(batchsize);

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe();
```

That's it.